# How to show the sum of the values for the same item and for different dates in react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, datatables

I have the array:

```
array = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "202001"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "I1"
    },
    "price": 100
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "date": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "202002"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "I1"
    },
    "price": 200
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "202002"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "I2"
    },
    "price": 300
  },
]
```

And I want to be able to display the data as shown in the table:

| ITEM | 202001 | 202002 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I1 | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| I2 | - | 300 | 300 |
| TOTAL | 100 | 500 | 600 |

I tried

```
  const items_dicc = array.reduce((acc, e) => {
    if (!acc[e["item"]["name"]]) {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]] = {
        [e["date"]["name"]]: e["price"]
      }
    } else {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]][e["date"]["name"]] = e["price"]
    }
    return acc
  }, {})

  const dates = [...new Set(Object.keys(items_dicc).map(i => Object.keys(items_dicc[i])).flat())]
```

to show the values of each date for the same item, now I need the above to calculate the subtotals and the total.

**EDIT**: Using @sabbir.alam answer

> totalSumPerDate = {}; dates.forEach(date => {   const sumOnDate =
> Object.values(items_dicc).reduce((acc, curr) => {
> acc = acc + (curr[date]? curr[date] : 0);
> return acc;   }, 0);   totalSumPerDate[[date]] = sumOnDate; });
>
> totalSum = Object.values(totalSumPerDate).reduce((acc, curr) =>
> acc+curr, 0);
>
> sumPerItem = {}; Object.keys(items_dicc).forEach(key => {    const sum
> = Object.values(items_dicc[key]).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);    sumPerItem[[key]] = sum; });

I did

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ITEM</th>
      {dates.map(date => <th>{date}</th>)}
      <th>TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {
    Object.keys(items_dicc).map((item) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{item}</td>
          {dates.map((date) => <td>{items_dicc[item][date] || ''}</td>)}
          {Object.values(sumPerItem).map((elem,i) => <td>{elem}</td>)}
        </tr>
      )
    })
  }
    <tr>
      <td>TOTAL</td>
        {Object.values(totalSumPerDate).map((elem,i) => <td>{elem}</td>)}
      <td>{totalSum}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to correct how the side subtotals are displayed.

How can I do it, suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following using reduce ,

```js
array = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "202001"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "I1"
    },
    "price": 100
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "date": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "202002"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "I1"
    },
    "price": 200
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "202002"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "I2"
    },
    "price": 300
  },
]


 items_dicc = array.reduce((acc, e) => {
    if (!acc[e["item"]["name"]]) {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]] = {
        [e["date"]["name"]]: e["price"]
      }
    } else {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]][e["date"]["name"]] = e["price"]
    }
    return acc
  }, {})

dates = [...new Set(Object.keys(items_dicc).map(i => Object.keys(items_dicc[i])).flat())]

totalSumPerDate = {};

dates.forEach(date => {
  const sumOnDate = Object.values(items_dicc).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc = acc + (curr[date]? curr[date] : 0);
    return acc;
  }, 0);
  totalSumPerDate[[date]] = sumOnDate;
});

totalSum = Object.values(totalSumPerDate).reduce((acc, curr) => acc+curr, 0);

sumPerItem = {};

Object.keys(items_dicc).forEach(key => {
   const sum = Object.values(items_dicc[key]).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
   sumPerItem[[key]] = sum;
});

console.log('Sum per item: ', sumPerItem);

console.log('Sum per date: ', totalSumPerDate);
console.log('TotalSum: ', totalSum);
```

Update for subtotal per item,

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ITEM</th>
      {dates.map(date => <th>{date}</th>)}
      <th>TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {
    Object.keys(items_dicc).map((item) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{item}</td>
          {dates.map((date) => <td>{items_dicc[item][date] || ''}</td>)}
          <td>{sumPerItem[item]}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
  }
    <tr>
      <td>TOTAL</td>
        {Object.values(totalSumPerDate).map((elem,i) => <td>{elem}</td>)}
      <td>{totalSum}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you very much for your help! It has worked perfectly to calculate the values for each date. I add an answer so you can see how I show the values. How do I now view the subtotals for each item?

Comment: One more doubt: I share an answer as I show it in a table, I need to correct the lateral subtotals.

Comment: Update the question so you can see how I display the values

Comment: Updated the code, if you have calculated sumPerItem beforehand, use `<td>{sumPerItem[item]}</td>` instead of mapping over sumPerItem.

Comment: Hello @sabbir.alam I have posted one more detail that I would need to understand to keep learning and developing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390482/show-a-pop-up-window-with-information-coming-from-an-element-and-its-totals-fro You can help me with that? Thank you!